# spring security: http if user not authenticate

Tags: spring, security

I'm using Spring 3.2 + primefaces 3.5 + hibernate 4.1.9
The security context is:

```
<http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true"   >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/login"  access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/registration" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/cart" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/cart/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/adm/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*/account**" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" />

    <form-login login-page="/loginRedirect"             
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="pennyUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="pennyAuthSuccessHandler"
        default-target-url="/pages/account/orders.xhtml" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/"  invalidate-session="true"/>
</http>
```

If I go to a page that requires HTTPS, for the rest of session, it will use the HTTPS protocol, even if the user is not authenticated.
If I go to https ://mystite/en/cart, HTTPS will be used for all browsing session.

I do not want to switch HTTPS to HTTP forever, but only if the user is not authenticated.
Can I force the HTTP for non-authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

> If I go to a page that requires HTTPS, for the rest of session, it
>   will use the HTTPS protocol, even if the user is not authenticated.

That's correct because of

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**/cart/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
```

Also, because of

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" />
```

it will stick with HTTPS once the user requested a resource that requires HTTPS. Why would it have to switch back if you say `any` (HTTPS is as good as any)?

> Can I force the HTTP for non-authenticated users?

No, not that I know of. Personally, I don't think this would make much sense either.